# Using a gateway for a private network interface on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I have a private network interface, as follows, on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM:

```
# Private network
auto ens19
iface ens19 inet static
    address 10.10.10.179
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    mtu 1450
```

My vLAN requires a gateway to be specified in order for it to work, so I append it as follows:

```
# Private network
auto ens19
iface ens19 inet static
    address 10.10.10.179
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    mtu 1450
    gateway 10.10.10.1
```

However, whenever I add that gateway and restart the `networking` service, it won't start with the following error:

```
Dec 15 10:50:08 postfix0 ifup[1968]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Dec 15 10:50:08 postfix0 ifup[1968]: Failed to bring up ens19.
```

Executing `ip addr flush dev xxx` does not help.

So, how do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ip addr instead of ifconfig reports "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100588/using-ip-addr-instead-of-ifconfig-reports-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-on-de)

Comment: @GAD3R The answer in that question does not solve my problem.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards – Did you try this?: https://serverfault.com/a/724090/375458

Comment: @TravisClarke Yes. Doesn't work: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Comment: @Christopher Yes to both.

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards Could you update your question to include the output of `ip addr` or `ifconfig -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a named routing table. The name, pvtnet, is arbitrary. This will not work if DHCP is handing out addresses on the 10.10.10 network.

```
echo '200 pvtnet' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Modify the file, `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# DHCP hands out the DEFAULT gateway.
auto eth0 # use the real device name on your system
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The private network interface
auto ens19
allow-hotplug ens19
iface ens19 inet static
address 10.10.10.179
netmask 255.255.255.0
mtu 1450
post-up ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 dev ens19 src 10.10.10.179 table pvtnet
post-up ip route add default via 10.10.10.1 dev ens19 table pvtnet
post-up ip rule add from 10.10.10.179/32 table pvtnet
post-up ip rule add to 10.10.10.179/32 table pvtnet
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! I tried many variations of that. Will award bounty in 23 hours when allowed.